# Why does incrementing a Java int eventually result in a negative number?

Tags: java

I was trying to check different inputs and creating infinite loops in java and I found that once the `int` is getting incremented over the maximum limit it turns in to negative `-2147482958`. I am just increasing the int in infinite loop...

#### Code:

```
public static void infiniteLoop(){
        for(int i=0;i>-1;i++){
            i = i + 1000;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

The last to value gets printed out is,

```
2147483337
-2147482958
```

Now, Why does it goes to negative?

Comment: If you want to be taken seriously you should really change the title.

Comment: @all, really sorry for little humour. I know it's a serious place, I was reading about halting problem and I was so frustrated by not finding a way to check if I can find the way to detect whether a program will halt with given input :)

Comment: @bmargulies, Thanks, sorry once again!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why does it goes to negative?

Because that is what is specified to happen in Java when an `int` calculation overflows.

[JLS 15.18.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)

> *"If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format. If overflow occurs, then the sign of the result is not the same as the sign of the mathematical sum of the two operand values."*

---

(This doesn't explicitly say that overflow always gives a negative number.  And it doesn't always.  But if you apply the rule, it does explain why incrementing `Integer.MAX_VALUE` by `+1` gives you `Integer.MIN_VALUE` ...)

Comment: +1, Thats interesting, thanks let me check the documentation! I should have done that before. thanks

Comment: It's surprising that it doesn't cause an exception.

Comment: @theglauber: I'm not sure it's that surprising.  In order to throw an exception, it would mean that every single arithmetic operation would have to be accompanied by additional cycles spent checking for overflow.

Comment: Some libraries have methods that check arithmetic for overflow, notably Guava's [`IntMath`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/math/IntMath.html) and Apache's [`ArithmeticUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils.html).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - right, that's why. But it feels a little un-java-ish. For example, C doesn't check for array access out of bounds for the same reason, but Java does. Just one of them things. Reminders that programming languages are always a series of compromises.

Comment: @theglauber - the difference between integer overflow and array out of bounds is that the latter could trample memory and CRASH the JVM if not caught.  You can't safely do (relocating) GC if there is undetected memory trampling.

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation:

The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 (0x80000000) and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (0x7FFFFFFF) (inclusive)

So when you add one to an integer's max value:

0x7FFFFFFF + 0x00000001 = 0x80000000 (-2,147,483,648)

Answer (score 4):

Because when the value of an int reaches [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE), incrementing it causes **overflow** and hence wraps around to [Integer.MIN_VALUE](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE).

To use larger integers, use a **long** instead which has **64 bits**.

Answer (score 1):

Because `int` ranges from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Hence,once it reaches it upper limit, it overflows and starts from the negative.

See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

*The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive)*