# Polynomial Root Finder Java

Tags: java

I am fairly new to Java and have created a Polynomial Root Finder with a GUI. One of the problems I am facing currently and don't quite understand is a value gained from perfect squares such as (x+5)^2.

```
int y = 0;
    for(int x = -100000; x < 100000; x++) {
        int math = (A * (x * x)) + (B * x) + C;
        if(math == 0) {
            Zeros[y] = x;
            y++;
        }
    }
```

Now for some reason Zeros[0] returns the value -65541 and I am unsure why. Now if I make the x boundaries from -10000 to 10000 the problem goes away and it shows the correct roots. I am just asking why -65541 is getting picked up as a root.

Here is a picture of my problem.

[image: Picture]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968733/why-does-incrementing-a-java-int-eventually-result-in-a-negative-number

Comment: Range of int varable –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 so, 2,147 Billions(US) and A(100000exp(2))=A*10exp(10)=A*10 Billions, so, overflow