# Why does trying to go up to 2,147,483,647 with a for-loop result in an infinite loop?

Tags: java

I have a program (code below) which simulates a dice rolling for a specified amount of rolls (`num;`) and then prints the result.
For some reason, the maximum amount of rolls the program can complete is 2,147,483,583 and not the int limit of 2,147,483,647. When 2,147,483,647 is entered as the number of rolls, the program simply never produces an output.

Is there a specific reason for this?

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class RollDie {
// number of rolls
private static float num = 2147483583;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.print("Rolling...\n");

    SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
    int frequency1 = 0;
    int frequency2 = 0;
    int frequency3 = 0;
    int frequency4 = 0;
    int frequency5 = 0;
    int frequency6 = 0;

    for (int roll = 1; roll <= num; roll++) {
        // randomly selecting face ('rolling')
        int face = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(6);

        switch (face) {
        case 1:
            ++frequency1;
            break;
        case 2:
            ++frequency2;
            break;
        case 3:
            ++frequency3;
            break;
        case 4:
            ++frequency4;
            break;
        case 5:
            ++frequency5;
            break;
        case 6:
            ++frequency6;
            break;
        }
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = ((end - start) / 1000);
    // displaying results
    System.out.println("\nFace\tFrequency");
    System.out.printf("1\t%d%n2\t%d%n3\t%d%n4\t%d%n5\t%d%n6\t%d%n",
            frequency1, frequency2, frequency3, frequency4, frequency5,
            frequency6);
    System.out.println("\nTime taken: " + totalTime + " seconds.");
  }
}
```

Comment: This question would've had a lot more future value if you debugged a bit to figure out what's going on here and asked a more specific question (or two).

Comment: any suggestions as to how I could edit my post to improve it?? @Dukeling

Comment: The problem is that to get to the ideal version of this question would require a fundamental change to your question, but doing that at this stage will invalidate parts of the answers, which is not good. More specifically, there are 2 issues here - (1) trying to represent large integers using `float` and (2) trying to loop up to 2,147,483,647 - those ideally should've been 2 separate questions, but both answers address both issues, so you can't really narrow it down now. What you can do, however, is [reduce your code as much as possible](https://ideone.com/CVZ0Gr).

Comment: Although proper debugging would've eventually led you to asking [Why does incrementing a Java int eventually result in a negative number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968733/why-does-incrementing-a-java-int-eventually-result-in-a-negative-number) (which would arguably make that a duplicate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no output because the for loop never terminates. You have to change the condition from `for (int roll = 1; roll <= num; roll++)` to `for (int roll = 0; roll < num; roll++)`.

In your case, roll reaches Integer.MAX_VALUE, the condition is **still true**, so the loop is entered once more. Now roll is increased, overflows to Integer.MIN_VALUE, and is **still <= `num`**. Hence, the for loop never stops.

In addition, you'll run into problems with `num` being `float`, see [Eran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45938175/7653073) for an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your `num` variable is of `float` type. The `float` type has limited precision, so it can't represent any large `int` value accurately.

The second issue was pointed by Malte - your loop won't terminate when you set the limit to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, due to `int` overflow.

If you change `num` to `int` and change the loop's condition to `roll < num`, the loop will terminate after the correct number of iterations.

Comment: Changing the type of `num` does not fix the issue completely. The reason why this is not working is the finish condition of the for loop. It never breaks because `roll` overflows. I agree, though, that num being float might need to an incorrect number of loop executions.

Comment: @MalteHartwig You are partially correct and I am partially correct. The full answer is a combination of both answers.Your solution will prevent the infinite loop, but the loop will exit prematurely (when roll==2147483584).

Comment: Yep, I changed my comment a bit. Have never used float much, funny how fast you run into problems there.

Comment: FWIW `float` can represent 2147483647 accurately.